# Paging horizontally between two table views in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I want to have two table views sitting horizontally next to each other. I am able to set up a `UIPageControl` along with a `UIScrollView` to page between two images, but how do I set up two `UITableView`s next to each other within a `UIScrollView` who's width is of `screenWidth*2` to page between the table views?

The tricky part is, once I get this to work, I need to be able to put the resulting construct itself into a `UITableViewCell` because the whole thing is also part of a bigger encompassing table view.

Would I create two different `UITableViewController` classes that each load their respective data, and then dynamically load those into `UIView`s of `screenWidth` width in the `UIScrollView`? I'm really lost here as to how to go about this.

Comment: Have you looked into `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Why do you need these 2 viewControls inside a uitableViewCell? Apart from this, everything else can be done.

Comment: This two table view with paging control is only part of my profile screen, and my profile is designed as a uitableview

Comment: Still working on my implementation, but it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `UIPageViewController`. Create your 2 `UITableViewController's` and set them as `- setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`. This will automatically handle the swipe between them. You wouldn't need to add them to a `UIScrollView`.